# Mean stack - angular 2 Site not loading completely

Tags: html, css, angular2-routing

I am currently using MEAN stack with angular 2.

Im unable to figure out where the concern is.

Im getting site which is incompletely loaded. Not sure if its CSS issue.

Here is the **folder structure** with **ports** configured for Angular 2 app.

But when i try to hit the page : http://my_ip:9200/admin/login  i get incompletely loaded css. ie) page doesnt load fully.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvd2M.jpg

**/var/www/html/Express/Local-MEAN-dev/index.js**

```
...
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
....
//Start Server: Listen on port 9000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mean-ang2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MEAN Stack with Angular 2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "cd client && ng build --prod"
  },
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": ""
   },
 "keywords": [
   ..
 ],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
  "url": ""
},
"homepage": "",
"dependencies": {
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.2.3"
}
}
```

Under **/var/www/html/Express/Local-MEAN-dev/admin**

Is where i have my angular 2 code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Food4Smiles</title>
  <base href="/admin">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/static/hmicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

To configure custom port for admin, i have edited the below file:

**\Local-MEAN-dev\admin\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js**

```
const defaultPort = process.env.PORT ||9200;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bootstrap css link in head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Oh man, why was this not working  ?: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">

Comment: You have used bootstrap 3.3.7 version but the link you used is different.